# Magento 2 generating invalid JS files

Tags: magento2, javascript

I have a Magento 2 install that is generating invalid JS files when I run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`. I get JS errors now on both the admin and frontend.

> E.g.
>   pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/i18n.js
>   - SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

```
   /**
     * execute i18n binding
     * @param {Object} element
     * @param {Function} valueAccessor
     * @param {bool} isUpdate
     */
    execute = function (element, valueAccessor, isUpdate) {
        var original = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor() || ''),
            el = getRealElement(element, isUpdate),
            inlineTranslation = (module.config() || {}).inlineTranslation;

        if (inlineTranslation) {
            setTranslateProp(el, original);
        } else {
            setText(el, "'"
    .addAttribute('translate', {
        binding: 'i18n'
    });
```

Comment: Not sure if you not post your current code related to issue . Try to rm -r pub/static/frontend/* pub/static/adminhtml/* pub/static/_requirejs/* and back reload page

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, and removing redeploying static files does not solve the problem

Comment: @Stephen could you tell me which recent modules have you installed ? as i said i have the exact same issue and still didn't find out a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You have changed "Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> JavaScript Settings -> Translation Strategy" option to "Embedded (Translation on Admin side)" value. 
Try to set back default system value "Dictionary (Translation on Storefront side)", js errors will disappear.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had this happen, to fix it I did the following:

I had written 6 custom modules, was running into a variety of these errors and wasn't sure when I had actually made the error happen.

All of my generated javascript assets were missing a closing ')'. The closing ')' of the define() wrapper.

I disabled all of my modules via command line 'bin/magento module:disable modulename' and it was still doing it. The error only stopped after I disabled all modules and ran 'bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f'. I'm running in developer mode, so you have to force it with '-f'.

I then enabled modules until the error returned. This gave me which module was causing the problem.

Upon reviewing that modules code, I found a line in my modulename/etc/adminhtml/system.xml was wrong. My `<resource>ModuleName::config</resource>` was defined from another module that I had copied over.

After fixing this and re-forcing the static-content deploy the issue resolved.

I suspect that it is a definition somewhere in your module's .xml configuration files. Be sure to check that all of your definition values are correct.

Hopefully this helps resolve the issue.

Comment: I ran into this again after deleting a di.xml file from a module. I was able to resolve it by 'bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f' again. Developer mode in magento 2 is supposed to generate these automatically... perhaps it is- but it doesn't seem to remove them automatically.